# sql float column padding some fraction and so boundary conditions fail

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have  a strange problem with the float data type.
Please find the screen shot below.

[image]

Query 1 gives a record. Where as Query 2 gives no record. netbk_amt is of type float in the table. 
Also, when i change the 1st query to `>= (convert(float, 100001))`, it doesn't give any records.

Looks like the value is > 1000000 but < 1000001. But in the table it is shown as 1000000.

Please help me to find what went wrong with this query.

Queries:

```
select co_id, SUM(netbk_amt) from its_deal_sum where co_id = 19237 
group by co_id
having convert(float,SUM(netbk_amt)) >= convert(float,1000000)

select co_id, SUM(netbk_amt) from its_deal_sum where co_id = 19237 
group by co_id
having convert(float,SUM(netbk_amt)) <= convert(float,1000000)
```

I kind of did this as suggested in comments,

```
select co_id, SUM(netbk_amt) from its_deal_sum where co_id = 19237 group by co_id having convert(money,SUM(netbk_amt)) = convert(money,1000000)
```

as a temporary fix. But looking for a robust fix with the float, ignoring the fractions.

Comment: Why are you using FLOAT for dollar amounts? I suggest you reconsider the data type.

Comment: Raghav, you wrote, "when i change the 1st query to >= (convert(float, 100001))". That number is 10^5 + 1. What you wanted was 10^6 + 1.

Comment: If the value of a float is computed as the difference between two floats, and either of those 2 floats cannot be represented accurately as a float, then the difference may be off by a small fraction. For example, 1000001.01 - 0.01 = 1000000.0000000000001. (I'm not sure of the exact amount of the error, but it can happen.) Like Aaron said, reconsider your data type. Float is inappropriate for money.

Comment: ...and so are MONEY/SMALLMONEY, IMHO.

Comment: @John Pick :Tat was a typo. i meant to type 10^6 +1.
This is a legacy application with a lots of dollar fields having float. Generally house keeping a old application with all such design bugs is a head ache. 
Also, its so huge that we cant change the design of many table, tat might lead to loss of data(referenced tables).

Comment: Could someone suggest a fix to handle the float amount without taking the fraction-corrections...?(I mean without changing the datatype)

Comment: I kind of did this, 
select co_id, SUM(netbk_amt) from its_deal_sum where co_id = 19237 
group by co_id
having convert(money,SUM(netbk_amt)) = convert(money,1000000)
as a temporary fix. But looking for a robust fix with the float ignoring the fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

> ignoring the fractions

is **all** what you want - it is very easy.

```
DECLARE @f float=2.000000000001
SELECT @f,FLOOR(@f)
```

Result set:

```
(No column name)    (No column name)
2.000000000001      2
```